# element can't seem to be located in webdriverio script

Tags: webdriver-io

Currently trying to test out the responsiveness on webdriverio. I adjust the viewport of my screen and then try to search for a table that exists at the bottom of the page (need to scroll to get into view port). For some reason, it can't locate the element and the test case fails.

```
it('should resize the table when screen width is mobile', () => {
    let mobileTable = $('.overview-table.mobile-table');
    browser.setViewportSize({
        width: 767,
        height: 500
    });
    //browser.pause(1500);
    mobileTable.waitForExist(10000);
    console.log(mobileTable);
    mobileTable.scroll();
    browser.debug();
});
```

I'm not sure if I'm getting the element right in the above code. I set mobileTable = $('.overview-table.mobile-table') because it is a table element with those classes

```
<table class="overview-table mobile-table"> ... </table>
```

I get the following error:

```
An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters (".overview-table.mobile-table").
running firefox
Error: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters (".overview-table.mobile-table").
    at scroll() - index.js:312:3
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem most likely is in your selector.

You can verify if your selector is correct by testing it into your browser javascript console.
In chrome it goes like this:

- Right click the page
- Inspect
- Select the "console" tab within the dev tool panel
- Then simply type $$('.overview-table.mobile-table')

If that's an empty array, then you know the selector is wrong.

Comment: yeah the selector is empty. I'm trying to figure out why it's wrong? the element is <table class="overview-table mobile-table"> ... </table> how would i grab this element?

Comment: actually, no the selector is not empty. I'm at a loss now. No idea what's wrong.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with selenium, as I am using appium on a daily basis. If you make your test scroll down to the said element, does it work ?
I know appium won't find the element unless it's visible in the viewport. Maybe that's the same on selenium.

Comment: it times out. As per the documentation here http://webdriver.io/api/utility/scroll.html

it says to set a variable to the css selector and call the scroll function.

Comment: apparently the scroll command is based upon touchScroll which is deprecated ([see doc](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/touchScroll.html)).
You should [use touchPerform](http://webdriver.io/api/mobile/touchPerform.html) instead